# Does an ordinary sword get cut in half when a lightsaber blocks it?

Tags: combat, weapons, star-wars-saga-edition

By the rules does a lightsaber cuts an ordinary steel sword in a half when the attack is blocked?
For example: A soldier wielding an ordinary steel sword makes an attack attempt against a jedi and the jedi blocks it with his lightsaber. Is the sword destroyed? Does it take damage? How does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There is no specific rule stating that.

**(Page 119)** Lightsabers ignore damage reduction unless specifically noted otherwise.

**(Page 122)** The saber can cut through most materials (except another lightsaber blade, an energy shield, or a few exotic materials) given enough time.

**(Page 152)** The GM may determine that certain weapons just can't deal damage effectively to certain objects. The GM may also rule that certain attacks are especially successful against some objects.

---

### Make A GM Ruling

A possible ruling could be that the ordinary steel sword takes damage by the lightsaber. I (personally as DM) would say to deal base damage (no modifiers) to the ordinary steel sword (since it is energy it should bypass hardness/damage reduction unless it is a special material that is resistent to energy).

---

As far as it cutting in half, I would say not unless it dealt enough damage to destroy it. The cutting in half could be the artistic license of describing enough damage to destroy the ordinary steel sword.

---

Source: Stars Wars Saga Edition Core Rulebook

Answer (score 1):

No.

The Block talent in no way indicates that it deals any damage to whatever attacked the character.  It does not cut a sword in half nor would it get to deal automatic damage to a character making Martial Arts attack against the Jedi.

See the "Attacking an Object" rule for attacks that would specifically target that sword in an attempt to destroy it.  Lightsabers' ability to ignore DR makes them very effective at damaging and destroying objects provided they can be hit.

Comment: +1 for showing how it's about the intention of the lightsaber wielder. They have to *want* to cut the sword.

Answer (score -1):

Usually a parry is just about making sure the sword doesn’t hit you— deflecting it, rather than stopping it. (Stopping someone else’s swing entirely means you just soaked up all that impact, which could stagger you and hurt your blade.) So in an ordinary fight, I would only expect the lightsaber to destroy the sword if the attack was a critical failure. A successful parry would give a cinematic shower of sparks.

The videogame *Knights of the Old Republic* has vibroblades made with a cortosis weave that makes them fully capable of stopping a lightsaber, and such blades are popular with people who think they might go up against a Jedi or Sith.

Comment: He had the tag Rules-As-Written in the question. It may be worth mentioning that destroying the sword due to a critical failure would/should be a GM Ruling.